# parsing variable composed with lettre and numbers like " JAVAC 1.7.0.XXX"

Tags: javacc

I'm trying to parse regular expressions using JavaCC but I encountered a problem with variable " Y " composed of lettre and number for exemple : " JAVA 1.7.1.XXX" . knowing that I have already defined the Token 
`<id > = < lettre > | <number> < #lettre : [ "A"-"Z", "a"-"z"]> | < #number : [ "0"-"9" ] >` in execution, the parser processing the first part of the variable " Y " like as `<id>`. after the parsing is stops.  Thanks in advance.

**Edit.**

Here code parseur.jj:

```
TOKEN : { <ID2 :  (["a"-"z","A"-"Z","0"-"9","_"])+
                  ( (["0"-"9"])+ "." (["0"-"9"])+ "." (["0"-"9"])+)+
                  (["a"-"z","A"-"Z","_","."])+ >}

TOKEN : { <ID : ["a"-"z","A"-"Z","_"] (["a"-"z","A"-"Z","0"-"9","_"])* >}
```

Suppose the remaining input steams starts with this : MyFile1_Test 1.2.3.txt
then the token `<ID>` is attributed ?

and not `<ID2>`.  normaly, why this rules not appilcatble : **If more than one regular expression describes a prefix, then a regular expression that describes the longest prefix of the input stream is used. (This
is called the “maximal munch rule”.)**   thank you very much for your help

Comment: Please show a complete minimal failing example.

Comment: Here are some code parseur.jj: TOKEN :
{

  < ID :
    < LETTER>
    (
      < LETTER >
    | < DIGIT >
    | "_"
    | "“"
    | ""
    | "."
    )* >
| < #LETTER :  [ "A"-"Z", "a"-"z","\u00AF"- "\u00FF" ,"“", "”", "•","." ] >
| < #DIGIT : [ "0"-"9" ] >

}


/* Numerals */
TOKEN :
{
  < Number : ([ "0"-"9" ] | "-")+ >
}

Comment: It's not a good idea to provide further information in an answer, so I've moved your "answer" to the end of the question. But it is still not clear to me what you are asking.    Perhaps you could provide a string or two and provide a description of how they should be broken into tokens.

Comment: I don't think the maximal munch rule comes into play, as any string that `ID2` matches has at least 2 `'.'` characters, while any string matched by `ID` has at most 0.

Comment: my question how can match string composed of "lettres" and "number.number.number.lettres" like  "MyFile   1.2.3.txt".

Comment: my question how I can match string composed of "lettres" and "number.number.number.lettres" like  for exemple "MyFile   1.2.3.txt". if I code TOKEN : { <ID2 :  (["a"-"z","A"-"Z","0"-"9","_"])+
                  ( (["0"-"9"])+ "." (["0"-"9"])+ "." (["0"-"9"])+)+
                  (["a"-"z","A"-"Z","_","."])+ >}

TOKEN : { <ID : ["a"-"z","A"-"Z","_"] (["a"-"z","A"-"Z","0"-"9","_"])* >}. ID2 is not mutch. for exemple IF the  input stream is "MyFile 1.2.3.txt" then  parser analyse : "MyFile" is < ID> , after  The caractere "1.2.3" like <NUMBERS> and the string "txt" like <ID>. thank you very

Comment: Are you saying you want "MyFile 1.2.3.txt" to be treated as a single `ID2` token?  If so you need to allow for spaces in the definition of `ID2`

Comment: the problem is solved. thank you very much for Help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the parseur.jj code:

```
TOKEN : { <ID2 :  (["a"-"z","A"-"Z","0"-"9","_"])+ ( (["0"-"9"])+ "." (["0"-"9"])+ "." (["0"-"9"])+)+ (["a"-"z","A"-"Z","_","."])+ >}

TOKEN : { <ID : ["a"-"z","A"-"Z","_"] (["a"-"z","A"-"Z","0"-"9","_"])* >}
```

Suppose the remaining input steams starts with: `MyFile1_Test 1.2.3.txt`
then the token `<ID>` is attributed and not `<ID2>`. Normaly, why this rules not applicable:

> If more than one regular expression describes a prefix, then a regular expression that describes the longest prefix of the input stream is used. (This is called the “maximal munch rule”.)

Comment: Another, Test is :TOKEN : { <ID :  (["a"-"z","A"-"Z","0"-"9","_","."])*  (["0"-"9","."])* >}.  Suppose the remaining input steams starts with this : MyFile1_Test 1.2.3.txt then the token <ID> is attributed at MyFile1_Test and the token <ID> is always attributed at String "1.2.3.txt"

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question.

Comment: @Raidri I guess this is meant as answer to self